# Per capita consumption in the steady state

Tags: macroeconomics

Could you please help me with the following question:
Suppose the saving rate is $20$%, population increases $3$% annually, and capital depreciates $3.5$% annually. What is the steady state value of per capita consumption. $\alpha = 0.6$

I want to use this formula but we do not know $A$.

$(1-s)A (sA /n + d)^{1/1-α}$

Comment: I meant I want to use C = (1-s)A (sA /n + d)^(1/1-α)   or should I use this formula  Css = (1 - s) Yss

Comment: From the information given above, we do not know either. If you find out what A stands for you will probably know how to solve this yourself, so I am voting to close this question.

Comment: A is for technology,

Comment: C is consumption, n is the growth rate of the population, d is the depreciation of capital

Comment: You can determine the value of A from the production function.

Comment: Please how do I go about that ?

Comment: What did you try ? please give us details of the model and show what you have tried.

Comment: Ok to me the model is Yt = Yt = A * K^α * L^1-α

Comment: I'm tryng to determine the steady state value of per capita consumtion C with the following formula  C = (1-s)A (sA /n + d)^(1/1-α)

Comment: All I need is a way to find A to be able to use the formula  C = (1-s)A (sA /n + d)^(1/1-α) . Then I can do it on my own. Please.

Comment: Alex it is quite unclear what you are asking. You tell us $Y_t = A \cdot K^{\alpha} \cdot L^{1- \alpha}$. If you have a formula for $Y_t$ then you have $A$. Without the formula we don't see how you could have it, there does not seem to be enough information. Perhaps you have a formula like  $Y_t = K^{\alpha} \cdot L^{1- \alpha}$. In this case the value of $A$ is obviously 1.